# React - TypeError: props.handleStatusClick is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component with a constructor that includes:

`this.handleStatusClick = this.handleStatusClick.bind(this);`

`handleStatusClick` is a function that takes 1 argument.
I then call the child component with the property:

`handleStatusClick={this.handleStatusClick}`

And inside of that child component i have:

```
<div style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick {props.handleStatusClick("starting")}>
```

I should mention that the child component is a presentational (stateless) component.

Why am i getting the

> TypeError: props.handleStatusClick is not a function

error?

Comment: As far as I see you need to adjust your div tag attributes to the following: `<div style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={() =>props.handleStatusClick("starting")}>`

Comment: you were missing the equal after onClick and the onClick prop needs a function but you were passing the returned value from the function

Comment: Yeah @Kabbany it works now! Thanks!

Comment: @Kabbany write it down as an answer for others who may get the same problem to see the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see you need to adjust your div tag attributes to the following:

`<div style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={() =>props.handleStatusClick("starting")}>`

you were missing the equal after onClick and the onClick prop needs a function but you were passing the returned value from the function